# Checking where each value comes from ArcGIS weighted sum?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster

I have five raster layers: all of them have values of 0 or 1 (boolean)

Via weighted sum function, i can check the total values on each cell (0-5).

If there is a cell with a value 4, how can i check which source layer had a zero ?

Is there a way i can create a table having all values from different layers so that I can check which layer got zero and what constraints the weighted layer has?

Comment: Use combine tool on all 5 of them

Answer (score 2):

You can do something similar with binary progression. The process is termed level-slicing by Joseph K. Berry. When categories are added together, one gets a unique value indicating what categories have contributed.

You could make the following changes to the values of your rasters:

0 to 1,  1 to 2,  2 to 4,  3 to 8,  4 to 16,  and 5 to 32.

So your five rasters would contain values of: R1) 1, 2 R2) 1, 4 R3) 1, 8 R4) 1, 16 and R5) 1, 32.

A summation with five pixels with value of 1 would be 5. Four pixels with 1 and one pixel with 2 would be 6. And so on. You could make a table to determine the summation value associated with combinations of various categories.