# Numeric sequence calculation

Tags: arcgis-desktop, classification

My doubt is that I have to do a calculation between 4 rasters. Each raster is classified in 1 to 5. So the final calculation must be a numerical sequence, like: 1111, 1321, 1555, 1432.... for example. Anyone knows how can I do that? Can be in ArcGis or QGIS?

Comment: First, you have to decide if you want to do it in ArcGIS or QGIS. Second, more than a calculation is a concatenation of a group of rasters

Comment: If you are trying to determine how each raster contributes to the final raster, [this question](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/245898/checking-where-each-value-comes-from-arcgis-weighted-sum/245906#245906) may provide some help.

Comment: Please choose exactly one platform. The Tour (which you've taken -- thanks!) emphasizes that only one question be asked per Question, but you've effectively got two questions, since the QGIS and ArcGIS solutions will be different.

Answer (score 1):

You don't say why you want to do this, but taking your request at face value, a very simple method could be to use the [raster calculator](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/tools/spatial-analyst-toolbox/raster-calculator.htm) and have an equation something along the lines of the following:

(a * 1000) + (b * 100) + (c * 10) + d

Make sure all your rasters have the same extent and that NoData is reclassified as zero appropriately.  This calculation will work (with appropriate syntax) in ArcGIS and QGIS (and probably most raster calculation environment.